# Is it possible to render HAML mockup on ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I've got ajax request with success function, also I've got HAML mockup. 
I want to generate with little mockup with passing there data from success respone, as I see everybody use it with erb, but I faced with syntaxis problem

here mockup:

```
%p
  %strong Commenter:
  = comment.commenter
%p
  %strong Comment:
  = comment.body
%p
  = link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment], |
    method: :delete,                                       |
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }                     |
```

it's sample of coffeescript.js

```
  success: (data, textStatus, jQxhr) ->
        console.log(data)
        $("#comments").append('')
```

Comment: I don't know, what are these `|` for?

Comment: @rony36 it's just a symbol)

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the goal you try to achieve? You want to trigger haml processing from your JS after response? (you can't do it, cause haml, just like erb, is processed at the server side). Or you have problems with haml server rendering?